# Finding if array contains three increasing consecutive numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

> Write a function that finds whether an array has 3 **increasing** consecutive numbers in it or not.
>   If there is, return 1. Otherwise, return 0.

```js
function tripleThreat(arr) {
   
    if (arr.find((i) => arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2])) {

      return 1
    }

    return 0

    }

tripleThreat([3,1,2,3]);
```

**Sample output**

`[...34,35,36...]` would return `1`

How would I write this using the `array.find()` method?

Some tests are passing, some aren't.

Right now, if I input `[3, 1, 2, 3]`, the result is `0` and not `1`.

Comment: why are you sorting your array?!

Comment: I guess i dont need it if im using the find method

Comment: No, you are irreversably destroying your input data by sorting. Also, `Array.prototype.sort` has only one parameter.

Comment: ok i took it out, i was trying to sort by increasing order

Comment: does `[3, 2, 1]` have three increasing consecutive numbers? Does the sorted version `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: gotcha, i see what i was doing wrong there.

Comment: Now, what are you trying to do by adding the values (apart from the problem, that `arr[i + 1]` may not exist, e.g. at the end of the array)? You want increasing consecutive numbers, what does the sum have to do with that?

Comment: not sure how to come up with a way to represent 3 increasing consecutive numbers that would work with the find method.

Comment: Do you have to use `find`? `some` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Ry- i don't have to, just would like to know how it works with find, but your suggestion is good too, would like to see how that would be implemented

Answer (score 1):

Use the 2nd parameter of `Array.find` to check the next two numbers for being greater than the current and the one after the current respectively. Don't forget to check if the array is long enough to have two more indices after the current one.

`Array.find` returns `undefined` if it can't find any matching elements, so if it returns `undefined`, then you know no such match exists and should return 0. Otherwise, return 1.

```js
function tripleThreat(arr) {
   
    if (arr.find((v,i) => 
            arr.length > i+2 
            && v < arr[i+1] 
            && arr[i+1] < arr[i+2]) === undefined) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

console.log(tripleThreat([3,1,2,3]));
console.log(tripleThreat([3,1,3,3]));
console.log(tripleThreat([0,1,2,2]));
console.log(tripleThreat([1,2,2.1,3]));
```

If you need to check if the values are consecutive whole numbers, check for equality to the current value plus one or two:

```js
function tripleThreat(arr) {
   
    if (arr.find((v,i) => 
            arr.length > i+2 
            && v + 1 === arr[i+1] 
            && v + 2 === arr[i+2]) === undefined) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

console.log(tripleThreat([3,1,2,3]));
console.log(tripleThreat([3,1,3,3]));
console.log(tripleThreat([0,1,2,4]));
console.log(tripleThreat([1,2,2.1,3]));
```

Comment: I think "increasing" in the mathematical sense is not just "+1", it is "greater than". However, i guess it may be better to ask OP for confirmation.

Comment: @ASDFGerte oh, I took  **consecutive** to mean consecutive in value as well as in index. You're probably right. Let me include that in my answer.